# Qual è il singolare di "rotini"? Anche, "tortiglioni"?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, grammatical-number

Qual è il singolare di "rotini"?  Ho trovato "spaghetto" vs "spaghetti" ma niente sui "rotini".
Grazie!

Per esempio, ecco un "rotini" in un sacchetto di tortiglioni": 
[image]

Comment: Che cosa intendi per “sii”?

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 8):

Il singolare di tortiglioni è [tortiglione](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tortiglione/).
*Rotini* (singolare, rotino, piccola ruota) non è il nome comunemente usato in italiano per indicare quel formato di pasta, diremmo:
"C'è un ***fusillo*** in un pacchetto di tortiglioni" :)